# Developer story tab doesn't appear on mobiles?

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

I just checked my [`user profile`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3102325/marian07) page and don't see the tab: `Developer story` on a Android phone.

Is public and appears on desktops.

Please check.

Comment: Is this about the app or about the mobile website?

Comment: It is about the website.

Comment: OK, that's not a bug, it simply doesn't exist for mobile. See the duplicate.